# Threading in Python for each item in list

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a list `H = [item1, item2, item3....so on]` and a function,

```
def start(item1):
    p1 = Do something to item1     
    return p1
```

I want the function start should run in parallel for each item in list H. I know multiprocessing, but I already have 4 list that runs in parallel using multiprocessing. While how the threading for each item in a list could be achieved? Can somebody please explain this with example code.

Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrency.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a function which runs a given function in a thread and stores the result:

```
import threading
def run_item(f, item):
    result_info = [threading.Event(), None]
    def runit():
        result_info[1] = f(item)
        result_info[0].set()
    threading.Thread(target=runit).start()
    return result_info
```

Then another function to gather the results:

```
def gather_results(result_infos):
    results = [] 
    for i in xrange(len(result_infos)):
        result_infos[i][0].wait()
        results.append(result_infos[i][1])
    return results
```

Then from the main thread, say `proc` is the function that processes an item and `items` is your list of items to process:

```
#start processing the items
result_infos = [run_item(proc, item) for item in items]
#gather the results (blocking)
results = gather_results(result_infos)
```

Example usage:

```
>>> import time
>>> def proc(item):
...     time.sleep(2.0)
...     return item * 2
... 
>>> print gather_results([run_item(proc, item) for item in [1, 2, 10, 100]])
#2 seconds later...
[2, 4, 20, 200]
```

Comment: Thanks! this help me alot. One more thing, if my list contain 10,000 items will 10,000 threads run in parallel? How much threads can we run in parallel? My list contain near about 20,000 items.

Comment: @user2766019: yeah this would run as many threads as items. you definitely don't want to do that. you should either use a threadpool, or keep a counter somewhere so if there's more than 10 threads already processing, you wait until you spawn more.

Comment: Hi, really sorry for this, but I am new to programming and not able to get where to use threadpool related to above code. Can you please explain threadpool using above code example. Thanks!