# How to read files in parallel in DataBricks?

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

Could someone tell me how to read files in parallel? I'm trying something like this:

```
def processFile(path):
  df = spark.read.json(path)
  return df.count()

paths = ["...", "..."]

distPaths = sc.parallelize(paths)
counts = distPaths.map(processFile).collect()
print(counts)
```

It fails with the following error:

> PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

Is there any other way to optimize this?

Comment: why not use threading?

Comment: @smx0 Could you point me any docs?

Comment: Might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322079/threading-in-python-for-each-item-in-list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run independent transformations in parallel using PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048068/how-to-run-independent-transformations-in-parallel-using-pyspark)

Comment: @user10938362 I'm sorry. I'm a little bit new in this. It looks like in these examples code will be invoked on the same machine. Is there a way to distribute computation among machines in a cluster?

Comment: @mazaneicha Thank you. Could you add an answer? I'll mark it as answer. In my case, it was enough. I grouped sources by type and passed to spark.read.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your particular case, you can just pass the whole `paths` array to DataFrameReader:

```
df = spark.read.json(paths)
```

...and reading its file elements will be parallelized by Spark.