# How can I parallelize a for loop for use in PyTorch?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytorch, tensor

I realize that `for` loops are slow with `Python` in general. I have some code that messes around with some tensors:

```
            for batch_index, mask_batch in enumerate(mask):
                mask_len = torch.sum(mask_batch).int()

                if mask_len == 0:
                    side_input = torch.zeros((max_inp_len, side_input.shape[1])).to(mask.device)
                else:

                    m_nonzero = mask_batch.nonzero().flatten()
                    first_nonzero = m_nonzero[0]
                    last_nonzero = m_nonzero[-1]

                    if side == 'left':
                        end_index = first_nonzero - 1
                        start_index = 0
                    elif side == 'right':
                        start_index = last_nonzero + 1
                        end_index = inputs[batch_index].size(1)

                    side_input = inputs[batch_index][start_index:end_index]

                    if end_index - start_index < max_inp_len:
                        pad_zeros = torch.zeros(
                            (max_inp_len - side_input.shape[0], side_input.shape[1])).to(mask.device)
                        if side == 'left':
                            side_input = torch.cat((pad_zeros, side_input), 0)
                        elif side == 'right':
                            side_input = torch.cat((side_input, pad_zeros), 0)

                side_inputs.append(side_input)

        return torch.stack(side_inputs)
```

I feel like this loop is REALLY slowing things down. Is there some way for me to do it without the loop?

Comment: Are not the for loop to be "slow"... How can you say that?
Anyway, if you do many slow operation in your loops consider using `threading` or `multiprocessing` libraries.

Comment: If your for-loop consists of iterating through a Tensor, and performing some operations on elements of the tensor, you should try to vectorize the operations.

Comment: Is it possible it's slow because you are accumulating gradients?  What if you put `with torch.no_grad()` in front of all your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python does not have true parallelism within any given process. You would have to spawn a ProcessPool and make the inside of your loop a function taking `batch_index, mask_batch`, then map that function over the `mask` object in your current for loop. Thing is, I don't know if PyTorch will play nicely with this.

Like so

```py
def f(batch_index, mask_batch):
    mask_len = torch.sum(mask_batch).int()

    if mask_len == 0:
        side_input = torch.zeros((max_inp_len, side_input.shape[1])).to(mask.device)
    else:
        m_nonzero = mask_batch.nonzero().flatten()
        first_nonzero = m_nonzero[0]
        last_nonzero = m_nonzero[-1]

        if side == 'left':
            end_index = first_nonzero - 1
            start_index = 0
        elif side == 'right':
            start_index = last_nonzero + 1
            end_index = inputs[batch_index].size(1)

            side_input = inputs[batch_index][start_index:end_index]

            if end_index - start_index < max_inp_len:
                pad_zeros = torch.zeros((max_inp_len - side_input.shape[0], side_input.shape[1])).to(mask.device)
                if side == 'left':
                    side_input = torch.cat((pad_zeros, side_input), 0)
                elif side == 'right':
                    side_input = torch.cat((side_input, pad_zeros), 0)
    return side_input
```

The other things you can look at are further vectorizing the code. Most things in PyTorch and Numpy can be vectorized away by using builtin functions and adding another dimension onto your tensors that represents the "loop" dimension. This will allow PyTorch to handle the parallelism for you.

PyTorch may have a concept of devices that you can put different iterations of the loop on, again this will require you to make a function for this loop and maybe take the device it goes on as an input.

Lastly you can look into just in time compliation like Numba or torch.jit to perform auto-vectorization for you.

None of this will work (most likely) if the `mask` is of an unknown length. If it is of a known length, I think vectorization, as hard as it is, is likely your best choice.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a function containing the logic behind a loop iteration, and launch it as a thread for each column (see [docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)). You could also use [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) library for concurrency but you might probably obtain less improvements.

A good example a spawning a thread for each element of a list can be read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322079/threading-in-python-for-each-item-in-list).